# Execute Puppet Code depending upon service status

Tags: puppet

How can we write a puppet manifest code that identifies whether a service(httpd) is running or not on puppet clients/agents. And if not, it should start that service and send out an email ?

```
class apache {
    package { mysql-server: ensure => installed }
    if hasstatus == "false" {
        service { "mysql":
            ensure => running,
            require => Package["mysql-server"],
        }
    }
}

node default {
    include apache
}
```

I know this is not a correct code. But I want to check hasstatus first and if the service status is false then I want to start service and send out an email.

Thanks 
Sanket Dangi

---

I have configured tagmail.conf in puppet master and have also enabled puppet reports but not able to receive mails to my gmail account. I can see puppet agent reports on puppet master but not receiving mails. Do I need to configure mail server for this ?

```
My Tagmail Conf : 
all: xxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puppet isn't an imperative shell script where you need to check the value of X before performing action Y that gets you to state Z.  Instead, you specify that you want state Z and Puppet checks the current state and handles the transition.

What this means is that you don't need to check the status of a service before deciding whether to start it or not and instead you declare that the *mysql* service *should be running* and Puppet ensures this is the case.

Simply have this in your manifest alongside the `package` line:

```
service { "mysql":
  ensure  => running,
  enable  => true,
  require => Package["mysql-server"],
}
```

The require line ensures the package is installed before evaluating or starting the service.

To send out notifications you can use the tagmail reporting feature in Puppet.  First set up a tagmail file ([reference docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/report.html#tagmail)) like this at `/etc/puppet/tagmail.conf` on the master:

```
mysql, apache: wwwadmins@example.com
```

And in the master's puppet.conf, set:

```
[master]
reports = tagmail
```

Ensure clients have report enabled in puppet.conf:

```
[agent]
report = true
```

This should then trigger e-mails relating to any resources with the "mysql" or "apache" tags (class names, module names etc).